Can I use $USER enviroment variable inside qemu.config?
I am installing my first KVM/QEMU based virt manager.
As per the instructions on Arch Wiki, one needs to change the config file of qemu.config.
sudo vim /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf

I used vim to edit the file and added a new user as described below.
I wonder if one can just add "$USER" and expect qemu to just use the current user.

Im going to use virt-manager as GUI, maybe that's important.
(Im using this other post as template, since both the questions are very similar to each other)

No, cos it makes no sense. For one typically programs don't expand an env var in a conf file. For two current user makes no sense for system daemon.

Oh... that makes a lot of sense. Thanks.
